# Outlook VBA -> Check the email extension of an address after it has been resolved

Tags: vba, email, outlook, resolution

I was wondering if there is a way i can modify my Item.To in the below code block to test against the physical email address?  Right now it is checking against the resolved name.

I.E. if i am testing for @here.com within John.Doe@here.com, and Outlook auto resolves the name, i'm left with a logic test of @here.com <> "John Doe".  Simply does not work.  Thanks for the assistance! Code follows:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
'**************************************************************************************************************************
'  Summary: Outlook BCC Insert util based by scan of to field for matching user
'       USAGE: populate user options and insert in to the "ThisOutlookSession" code body in Outlook
'**************************************************************************************************************************
'  History:
'       05/04/2015  Me                    Created
'**************************************************************************************************************************

Dim objRecip As Recipient
Dim strMsg As String
Dim res As Integer
Dim EmailToCheckAgainst As String
Dim BCCEmailToAdd As String

On Error Resume Next

    ' #### USER OPTIONS ####
    EmailToCheckAgainst = "@here.com" 'email address you are checking against
    BCCEmailToAdd = "BCCme@mycompany.com" 'email address you are adding as BCC
    ' #### END USER OPTIONS ####

    If InStr(LCase(Item.To), LCase(EmailToCheckAgainst)) > 0 Then
        Set objRecip = Nothing
        Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(BCCEmailToAdd)
        objRecip.Type = olBCC

        'Resolve it?
        Cancel = False
        If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
            strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
            "Do you want still to send the message?"
            res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
            "Could Not Resolve Bcc Recipient")
            If res = vbNo Then
                Cancel = True
            End If
        End If

    End If

On Error GoTo 0
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Do no use the To/CC/BCC properties. Loop through all recipients in the MailItem.Recipients collection and compare the Recipient.Address property (if it is resolved) or Recipient.Name if it is not.